# C++ Copy Raw std::bytes to std::vector<std::byte>

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, std-byte

I have an `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` struct which i have filled like this:

```
FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* fni = new FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION;
fni->Action = 1;
wcscpy_s(fni->FileName,12, L"example.txt");
fni->FileNameLength = 12;
fni->NextEntryOffset = 0;
```

I have then castet this Struct to an `std::byte*`.

```
auto fni_as_byte = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(fni);
```

Now i want to put this `fni_as_byte` into an vector of `std::vector<std::byte>`.
Because i need this for testing purpose.

Normally you receive the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` for example from the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` function.
And it's called like this:

```
std::vector<std::byte> notifyBuffer(1024);
res = ReadDirectoryChangesW(handle, notifyBuffer.data(), static_cast<DWORD>(notifyBuffer.size()), false, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME, nullptr, &overlapped, nullptr);
```

So how can i manually copy the castet `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` into the `std::vector<std::byte>`?

Comment: memcpy, std::copy, a for loop. All the usual options apply.

Comment: `std::vector<std::byte> notifyBuffer{1024};` -- This creates a vector of one element, with that value being 1024.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Have I missed something? Did uniform initalisation change? There's a [constructor accepting a size parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which should be called then – unless I'm not up to date... In any case, this unclearness is the reason I consider uniform initialisation flawed and it should not be used. `notifyBuffer(1024)` or `notifyBuffer({1024})` are so much more obvious...

Comment: @Aconcagua `std::vector` also has a constructor that takes a `std::initializer_list`. That is the constructor that `notifyBuffer{1024}` will call, not the size constructor you are thinking of. If that `initializer_list` constructor didn’t exist, then yes, the size constructor would be called instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK, then I have missed a change in the course of the standards. I still recall UI preferring the non-initialiser list constructors, if there are. Another breaking change then. Can you tell which standard changed that? Still even more convinced not to use UI...

Comment: @Aconcagua your recall is incorrect. Since its introduction in C++11, UI has always performed a 2-phase lookup, looking only at `std::initializer_list` constructors first, and if no match is found then looking at all other constructors.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see. Thanks. I recall getting different results when explicitly testing, but must have been a non-conformant compiler then. Still there are ambiguities possible. And own code might break if some library adds a initialiser list constructor that wasn't there before. Not the same, but [this one](https://probablydance.com/2013/02/02/the-problems-with-uniform-initialization/) makes me stay with my mind (*required* double brace syntax for initialiser lists, `v{1024}` with 1024 elements and `v{{1024}}` with one single element would have broken my opposition against, but too late...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is corrupting memory, as the actual size of `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` is variable length. See [Why do some structures end with an array of size 1?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043).  You are not allocating enough memory to hold the string you are copying into the `FileName`. To allocate your `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` *correctly*, you would need to do something more like this instead:

```cpp
FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* fni = (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*) new std::byte[offsetof(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION, FileName[12])];
fni->Action = 1;
wcscpy_s(fni->FileName, 12, L"example.txt");
fni->FileNameLength = 11 * sizeof(WCHAR); // <— expressed in BYTEs, not including the null terminator!
fni->NextEntryOffset = 0;
...
delete (std::byte*) fni;
```

That being said, to copy the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` into a `std::vector`, you can do it like this:

```cpp
FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* fni = ...;
// fill fni as needed...
std::vector<std::byte> buffer(offsetof(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION, FileName) + fni->FileNameLength);
std::memcpy(buffer.data(), fni, buffer.size());
// use buffer as needed...
```

Alternatively, just use the `std::vector` up front as the memory for the original `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`:

```cpp
std::vector<std::byte> buffer(offsetof(FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION, FileName[12]));
auto fni = reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*>(buffer.data());
// fill fni as needed....
// use buffer as needed...
```

Comment: Note that the last one will break when `buffer` reaches end of scope, as `fni` doesn't own the data.

Comment: @JHBonarius in the 2nd example, `fni` is declared after `buffer`, so `fni` will go out of scope first. The only way that code would break is if that pointer is saved somewhere else, and then used after `buffer` is destroyed.

Comment: Exactly... what if the OP (or some future reader) decides to put this code in a function and `return fni;`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau i tried your first solution but it did not work completly. I was able to put the `fni` inside the vector but if i try to read it back from the `vector` to the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` Struct with an `reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*>` the Filename Parameter inside the `fni` is not filled completly. It seems the `sizeof(*fni)` returns a wrong size of the struct

Comment: @Kevin you are right, I didn’t take into account that the size of `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` is [variable length](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040826-00/?p=38043). But then, neither does your original code, either. So you are actually corrupting memory. I will update my answers to reflect this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau would it work if i calculate the size like this:
`auto size = sizeof(*fni) + fni->FileNameLength` ?

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for the edit and the explanation. I have tried it out but now the `FileName` inside the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` is to large if i cast it back from the vector.  BEcause the `FileNameLength` is calculatet to 22 but the `FileName` Length is only 12. So 10 extra characters are added to the Filename.

Comment: @Kevin Read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-file_notify_information). `FileNameLength` is in bytes and does not count the trailing null. And `FileName` is Unicode and does not contain a null character. Now do the math.

Comment: @Kevin the `FileName` is 11 *characters* (not counting the null terminator) that take up 22 *bytes*. Per the documentation: “*`FileNameLength` -The size of the file name portion of the record, **in bytes. Note that this value does not include the terminating null character**. `FileName` - A variable-length field ... The file name is in the **Unicode character format and is not null-terminated**.*” Windows uses UTF-16 for Unicode strings. If you are having trouble getting the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` out of the `vector` then you are likely not taking these facts into account properly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau @j6t sorry guys im dumb =) in the codebase where i used the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION` from the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` Function i received the `Filename` by doing the Math correct so sorry for that dumb comment =).
`std::wstring wPathName(notIf.FileName, notIf.FileName + (notIf.FileNameLength / sizeof(notIf.FileName)))`

Comment: @Kevin `sizeof(notIf.FileName)` should be `sizeof(WCHAR)`. They *happen* to be the same byte size in this situation, but you should write your code to be easier to read and understand. In that same vein, I would also suggest use the `wstring` constructor that takes a size parameter, rather than iterators: `std::wstring wPathName(notIf.FileName, notIf.FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR));`